# How can I change two different buttons' text if I switch between two language buttons?

Tags: reactjs, state

My main problem is that when I switch from "ENG" to "HUN" button, the "Home" and the "New Game" text button don't transform to the Hungarian equivalent.

- { LangButton } component switches "ENG" to "HUN". When the "HUN" button active, should transform any innerText. Those innerText changes are stored in { languages } object, what is also a different js file.

[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZYTW.png)

Current codes are here, LangButton used as a Child component in Header.js file;

LangButton.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ".././Header_module.css";

export const LangButton = ({ hunLang, setHunLang, num, text, onClick }) => (
  <button
    onClick={() => setHunLang(num)}
    className="button"
    style={{
      backgroundColor: hunLang === num ? 'white' : 'black',
      color: hunLang === num ? 'red' : 'rgb(112, 255, 0)',
      borderRadius: num === 1 ? '5px 0 0 5px' : '0 5px 5px 0',
      marginRight: num === 2 ? '10px' : '0px',
      onClick: {onClick}
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </button>
);
```

Header.js file:

```
import "./Header_module.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { LangButton } from "./Language/LangButton";
import { languages } from ".././languages";


const Header = (props) => {
    const [hunLang, setHunLang] = useState(1);
    const [homeButton, setHomeButton] = useState(languages.en.home_btn);
    const [newGameButton, setNewGameButton] = useState(languages.en.new_game_btn);

    const engButtonClick = () => {
        setHomeButton(languages.en.home_btn);
        setNewGameButton(languages.en.new_game_btn);
    };

    const hunButtonClick = () => {
        setHomeButton(languages.hu.home_btn);
        setNewGameButton(languages.hu.new_game_btn);
    };

    return ( 
    <div className="header-bg">
        <div className="btn-container">
            <button className="button">{homeButton}</button>
            <button className="button">{newGameButton}</button>
            <LangButton
            hunLang={hunLang}
            setHunLang={setHunLang}
            num={1}
            text="ENG"
            onClick={engButtonClick}
            />
            <LangButton 
            hunLang={hunLang}
            setHunLang={setHunLang}
            num={2}
            text="HUN"
            onClick={hunButtonClick}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added two `onClick` handlers including one inside a style block of `LangButton` component.

It works after fixing it:

```js
const languages = {
  en: {
    home_btn: "Home",
    new_game_btn: "Game"
  },
  hu: {
    home_btn: "Home hu",
    new_game_btn: "Game hu"
  }
};

const LangButton = ({ hunLang, num, text, onClick }) => (
  <button
    onClick={onClick}
    className="button"
    style={{
      backgroundColor: hunLang === num ? "white" : "black",
      color: hunLang === num ? "red" : "rgb(112, 255, 0)",
      borderRadius: num === 1 ? "5px 0 0 5px" : "0 5px 5px 0",
      marginRight: num === 2 ? "10px" : "0px"
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </button>
);

const Header = (props) => {
  const [hunLang, setHunLang] = React.useState(1);
  const [homeButton, setHomeButton] = React.useState(languages.en.home_btn);
  const [newGameButton, setNewGameButton] = React.useState(
    languages.en.new_game_btn
  );

  const engButtonClick = () => {
    setHunLang(1);
    setHomeButton(languages.en.home_btn);
    setNewGameButton(languages.en.new_game_btn);
  };

  const hunButtonClick = () => {
    setHunLang(2);
    setHomeButton(languages.hu.home_btn);
    setNewGameButton(languages.hu.new_game_btn);
  };

  return (
    <div className="header-bg">
      <div className="btn-container">
        <button className="button">{homeButton}</button>
        <button className="button">{newGameButton}</button>
        <LangButton
          hunLang={hunLang}
          setHunLang={setHunLang}
          num={1}
          text="ENG"
          onClick={engButtonClick}
        />
        <LangButton
          hunLang={hunLang}
          setHunLang={setHunLang}
          num={2}
          text="HUN"
          onClick={hunButtonClick}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```